# How to build PIPO register

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, logic-gates, register, nand

Ive got problem with simulating 8-bit register. Ive built register using eight D flip - flop. Every flip-flop was made with 5 NAND gates + 2 NAND gates for Preset. My problem is that register doesnt really store input value. When ie D0 change to 1 the Output Q0 change to 1 but when Input change back to 0 output change as well. Do I need some extra latch on output or input? Ive added three-state buffers on inputs and outputs pins and it works good but when I change "Input enabled" pin to 0, buffers outputs change to 0 and register is changing output.
Is this regular behaviour of regsiters or I should add something to this circuit?
[image: 8-bit register, D flip-flops, NAND]

---

Should I use flip flop like this one? 
[image: RS flip flop]

Comment: A register is just a dual input S/R dual gate which is set or reset. A FF uses two such pairs and inverts input for this to AND CLK edge latch for a 8bit register with latch input on edge. Where is your CLK? YOu can delay IE with a 1 shot or s/w delay to latch.

Comment: Ok, so now ive built single RS flip - flop with four NAND gates. To build 8 - bit PIPO register I could just connect 8 rs flip - flops. unfortunately I dont know how register change his value. For example in first step we want to store 0xFF value in register so on every output we would have "1". To do this We enable Input, flip - flops are changing their states. In next step we disable input buffers and now our register remember 0xFF. What should I do to clear just one bit in this register? Imagine that in second step i need to write 11100111b. should I have "clear" pin in my register?

Comment: You need a Clock signal instead of INput enable. FF' are actually done with TG's instead of gates.  Have you looked ?

Answer (score 0):

What you have constructed would more properly be called a "latch" (level-sensitive) rather than a "register" (edge-sensitive). In order for it to hold the data, you need to drive the `Clk` input low.

In other words, whenever `Clk` is high, the output will follow the input, as you have described. When `Clk` is low, the output will retain whatever value the input had at the moment `Clk` went from high to low.